# facebook login error. unable to get user_birthday and user_location

Tags: android, facebook

Hi i am using facebook to login to my app. I am unable to get user

birthday and user location from facebook. Below is the method used to get the details from user. I am using activity class for login.

```
          private void loginFacebook() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        final Session.OpenRequest request = new 

       Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this);

        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { 

    "email","user_birthday","user_about_me","user_location"
         }, new LoginDialogListener());

    } else {
        getProfileInformation();


    }
}

    public void getProfileInformation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {

        profile = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("me"));
        mUserId = profile.getString("id");
        Gloabalvariables.setUserID(mUserId);
        mUserToken = facebook.getAccessToken();
        mUserName = profile.getString("name");
        mUserEmail = profile.getString("email");
        JSONObject c=new JSONObject(profile.getString("location"));
        mUserhomeTown=c.getString("name");

        new insertintoServer().execute();
        //getOnlineFreindList();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + mUserName            "\nEmail+"+ mUserEmail, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } catch (FacebookError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here the problem is i can able to get user_birthday and user_location from the user only for the account which i created app id. For other account i am unable to get those details. i am struggle for two days. But i dint find what i did wrong in the code.

Comment: have you gave permission in facebook developer account ?

Comment: Facebook policy has been changed, you can access only those user details who are using your application, and that too only basic details such as profile_info and location, for any thing else you need to get permission pre approved via there console.

Comment: how to give permission in facebook developer console.

Comment: @Techfist please provide me some link how to give permission

Comment: am assuming you have already created an facebook ap and have registered you key has, after this go to facebook developer console, and open up your facebook app, under you facebook app you will tab status and review of left, there you have list of pre approved items, and option to start an submission for extra permission, check that. hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Facebook Developer Console set permissions:

[Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/241596195983264/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.0)

There:

1. Application
2. Get Access Token:  Here select your fieds which you want.
3. Search For Field
4. Submit
5. Save Session

Comment: here also i am unable to get details of user other than account where i created my app id

Comment: Use that FB account where your app create and follow that steps, you can access all users data which login

Comment: if i login using another user account i am unable to get that data

Comment: i follow all steps.. still i am not able to get it. i want to change anything in coding

Comment: i can able to get details for the user where i created my app id. but if i login with another user i am unable to get that details

Comment: profile.getProperty("location").toString(); use that

Comment: The method getProperty(String) is undefined for the type JSONObject

Comment: don't use json, try that String location=profile.getProperty("location").toString();

Comment: You make some changes like that which disscuss you